# Ideals with norm in arithmetic progression

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

Let K/Q be a number field extention. Is there an asymptotic formular for the numer of ideals $\sum\limits_{\substack{N(A)\leq x\\N(A)\equiv k(q)}}1$,where $(k,q)=1$ and $A$ runs over ideals in $O_K$. If there was, where to find.

Comment: Welcome to MO! I think it would be a good idea to provide more details and a motivation for your question.

Comment: I second UwF. You should edit your question and precise  at least in what rings are taken your ideals (presumably the ring of integers of a number fields) and what you mean by arithmetic progression in this context.

Comment: Dear Kui Liu, I think such a formula can be obtained by  the methods of Lang, Algebraic Number Theory, chapter 6, section 3. Did you know this reference?

Comment: Dear Joël，thank you very much. I know that reference, but I am not familiar with the adele language of that book. Is the method there similar to the method in this paper? http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0723086906000375